# HDF5 - C++ - open a file to read the contents failed

Tags: c++, linker-errors, hdf5

I tried writing a really short script just to open an hdf5 file but it does not work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "H5Cpp.h"

#ifndef H5_NO_NAMESPACE
    using namespace H5;
#endif

const H5std_string FILE_NAME( "testfile.h5" );

int main (void)

{

    H5File openFile( FILE_NAME, H5F_ACC_RDONLY );

}
```

I'm pretty sure that I included the hdf5 library and the path to the includes.
But nevertheless I get the error message from the linker:

```
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -L/usr/local/pub/lib64 -L/usr/local/pub/lib -L/lib64 -L/usr/lib64 -o "HDF5_CPP"  ./openfile.o   
./openfile.o: In function `main':
/athome/augs_ay/workspace/HDF5_CPP/Debug/../openfile.cpp:18: undefined reference to `H5check_version'
/athome/augs_ay/workspace/HDF5_CPP/Debug/../openfile.cpp:18: undefined reference to `H5::FileAccPropList::DEFAULT'
/athome/augs_ay/workspace/HDF5_CPP/Debug/../openfile.cpp:18: undefined reference to `H5::FileCreatPropList::DEFAULT'
/athome/augs_ay/workspace/HDF5_CPP/Debug/../openfile.cpp:18: undefined reference to `H5::H5File::H5File(std::string const&, unsigned int, H5::FileCreatPropList const&, H5::FileAccPropList const&)'
/athome/augs_ay/workspace/HDF5_CPP/Debug/../openfile.cpp:18: undefined reference to `H5::H5File::~H5File()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [HDF5_CPP] Error 1
```

can anyone help?
Thank You!

Comment: You need to add `-lhdf5_cpp -lhdf5` to your build command.

Comment: I'm using eclipse for building. How can I do this here?

Comment: Ah I found! Properties - C/C++ Build - Settings - Linker Libraries Thank you! It worked

Answer (score 7):

For those using CMake, here is an example:

(the undefined reference problem is solved in the last line)

```
find_package(HDF5 COMPONENTS C CXX HL REQUIRED)
link_directories( ${HDF5_LIBRARY_DIRS} )
include_directories( ${HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
add_executable( convert_to_hdf5 src/convert_to_hdf5.cpp )
target_link_libraries( convert_to_hdf5 ${HDF5_CXX_LIBRARIES} )
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd just like to leave a note to everyone else who reaches this place in the future, struggling with the same problem:

If you're choosing to use `g++` with flags to compile your code instead of the hdf5-provided `h5c++` script, make sure the flags you use are from `h5c++ -show` instead of `h5cc -show`, as the latter is for the straight C version.

Answer (score 0):

Extending the answer for Bazel users.
What helped me was to add the flags from the original comment to "linkopts".
That is:

```
cc_binary(
    name="h5-test",
    srcs=[
    "cpp/read_h5_test.cpp"
],
    copts=[]
+ select(
    {
        "//conditions:default": [
            "-I/usr/include/hdf5/serial/",
        ],
    }
),
    includes=[
    "inc"
],
    linkopts=[
    "-lhdf5_serial",
    "-lhdf5_cpp",
],
    visibility=[
    "//visibility:public"
],
)
```